# Network Error on Lambda function with headless browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm trying to test a function on AWS Lambda. The function opens a headless version of Chromium through Puppeteer. The browser gets opened by `chrome-aws-lambda`, in order to avoid uploading the whole browser.
I deploy my Lambda through Serverless, and interact with a DynamoDB table for other purposes, if this helps.

The following function checks the presence of an Ad on a youtube video:

```
async function checkAdsPresence(page, adSelector) {
  await delay(10000);
  try {
    const module = await page.evaluate((adSelector) => {
      const adModule = document.querySelector(adSelector);
      const adType = adModule.children.length;
      const presence = adType > 0;
      return presence
    }, adClass);
    return module
  } catch (err) {
    return "No ad module"
  }
}
```

This function gets called repeatedly and waits for 10 seconds, as you can see from the delay function, which is defined as follows.

```
function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
}
```

But after calling the function a few times, about 4 (so 40 seconds in the video), the Lambda panel shows the following error.

`Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error`

No other error shows in my logs, it just stops, no other info. Any idea of what could cause this?

Comment: Is your lambda function inside a VPC?

Comment: @Andre.IDK no, I deployed my lambda through Serverless, I'll edit to add some infomation

Comment: @Andre.IDK in my case is in VPC, some suggetion?

Comment: @DouglasOliveira check security group associated with the Lambda, then routing tables

Comment: Thanks @Andre.IDK I changed the code implementation, I think that the problem is related with amount of data that my lambda were handling, then I splited the execution into more limited parts calling the same lambda several times but with less data, so worked weel.